# How to group data from this several data frame in list by using or loop or list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list which contain several dataframes (50 dataframes, actually) name ‘interest_period’. Each contains 5 columns of data, ‘DATE-Time’, ‘KWH’, ‘normdata’,’weeknumber’ and ‘dayofweek’, respectively.

My individual dataset such as interest_period[0] look like this

[image]

And others contain data in the same format. My goal is trying to group data by using DataFame.groupby on column name ‘weeknumber’ by this following code:

```
grouped_week = [interest_period[x].groupby('weeknumber') for x in range(len(interest_period))]
```

However, This code doesn’t work and complier always shows this error :

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupby'

So,how can I fix this problem to complete my task.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a compiler error. This is a runtime error, and it's telling you that at least one of the items in your list is in fact *not* a dataframe, but `None`. and doing `(None).groupby` would cause that attribute error.

Comment: Also, in general, `[<somethign with mylist[i]> for i in range(len(mylist))]` should just be `[<something with x> for x in mylist]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple list comprehension:

```
grouped_week = [period.groupby('weeknumber') for period in interest_period]
```

if there is still an AttributeError use an additional if filter on None

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, it is still show the same error. Cloud you please tell me that how to use an additional if filter on None ?

Comment: sure: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions